# Lógica del funcionamiento de una función dentro de otra función

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tardes a todos:

A inicios de este año inicie con el aprendizaje de **Python 3** de manera autodidacta, sin embargo me he encontrado con este código del cual no comprendo la lógica:

```
def add_ten(x):
    return x + 10

def twice(x, b):
    return x(x(b))

print(twice(add_ten, 10))
```

¿Alguien me podría explicar de manera detallada porque el resultado de la impresión de la llamada de la función `print(twice(add_ten, 10))`  da 30?

Gracias por su comprensión, tiempo y ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, edité tu código ya que no estaba bien la identación del mismo, en Python es fundamental esto por que determina la lógica de ejecución. Luego de la definición de cada función correspondía un bloque de identación. En cuanto a tu pregunta, la explicación sería la siguiente:

1. El print se hace del retorno de `twice(add_ten, 10)`
2. `twice` es una función que recibe el nombre de una función (parámetro `x`) y un valor (parámetro `b`), lo que le estamos pasando es `add_ten` y el valor `10`
3. `twice` lo que hace es `return x(x(b))` es decir invocar dos veces a la rutina `add_ten` -> `add_ten(add_ten(10))`
4. `add_ten` simplemente suma 10 al valor recibido, al llamarlo dos veces de manera anidada con el valor 10, lo que se termina haciendo es: `10 + 10 + 10`

Si lo quieres ver de forma coloquial, sería: **dos veces sumarle 10 al valor 10**

Comment: con que valor estaria entrando add_ten dentro del print?

Comment: El valor que imprime el `print` es `twice(add_ten, 10)`, el valor inicial es el `10` lo que se termina haciendo es `add_ten(add_ten(10))` es decir `30`

Comment: El punto 3 de tu comentario es el que no me quedaba claro, no encontraba la conexión entre las dos funciones. En cuanto a a indentación estoy usando PyCharm que realiza un excelente formato sobre el código, el problema es que al pasarlo al editor de StackOverflow no reconoce espacios ni indentación. Gracias por tu respuesta @Patricio Moracho